# 'Edit Properties' is greyed out for a Blog

Tags: sharepoint-online, blog

I have to create a small Intranet site for my company and I have to work with SharePoint Online. 
I added a Blog (from the prebuild template) for publishing articles but I cannot edit the page at all because the 'Edit Properties' button is greyed out.

Does anybody know how to edit the site?

Thank you.

EDIT: Mixed up 'Edit Properties' and 'Edit site', corrected it.

Comment: Site edit or Edit page?

Comment: Used the wrong english expression, corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar option in SharePoint Online trying to edit a Blog site homepage. **Enable the site feature "Site Pages"**, then you can edit the blog homepage. To verify its not permissions, use a site collection admin account to test.

I blogged the solution here: https://eschrader.com/2018/02/28/sharepoint-online-blog-site-how-to-edit-the-homepage/

[image: Enable the Site Pages feature, then you can edit the Blog site homepage]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all pages are checked in, it could be that the default page is checked out from the initial creation of the site.

Answer (score 0):

It's SharePoint OOTB page so we can't edit properties for that page. It is limitation by design.

You can edit properties of pages which are under "**Site Pages**" and "**Pages**" library.

Comment: Ok, let's say I want to edit this [picture](http://i.imgur.com/s9lvPoh.png). How should I do it? (sorry for the noob-ish question)

Comment: It's not image but it is different different web part. You need to learn how to edit web part.

Comment: I just want to edit the blog like [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/646676). Seems like it was possibly in previous versions but isn't in the recent SharePoint Online.

Comment: No I don't think it was possible. SharePoint don't allow us to edit OOTB pages.

Comment: Seems like it was [possible](https://youtu.be/p47gjD4yMC0?t=3m38s). Could you tell me where to edit the web part (and the picture) now? I seems like I am unable to find it online.

Comment: You just need to edit page from ribbon. And then edit web part.

Answer (score 0):

Update on this for those who have noted that this did not fix Blog subsites in Team sites.

There is a default Deny on the Team sites that blocks the editing of the subsite.
The attributes returned from
***Get-SPOSite siteurl*** include:

**DenyAddAndCustomizePages : Enabled**
Set this attribute to Disabled or $False using

***set-SPOSite siteurl -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $False***